# $addFields inside an array of objects

Tags: mongodb

Please consider the following data:

```json
{
  "_id": "F9F39JQH",
  "field": {
    "array": [
      {
        "itemId": 1
      },
      {
        "itemId": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add a single field inside the first element or the `array`.

```json
{
  "_id": "F9F39JQH",
  "field": {
    "array": [
      {
        "itemId": 1,
        "newField": "val"     <- add this field & value.
      },
      {
        "itemId": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried executing either of the following pipeline updates:

```js
const pipelineUpdate = [
    { $addFields: { "field.array.0": { newField: "val" } } }
];
const pipelineUpdate2 = [
    { $addFields: { "field.array.0.newField": "val" } }
];
db.users.updateOne({ _id: "F9F39JQH" }, pipelineUpdate);
```

But the result is quite unexpected:

```json
{
  "_id": "F9F39JQH",
  "field": {
    "array": [
      {
        "0": {
          "newField": "val"
        },
        "itemId": 1
      },
      {
        "0": {
          "newField": "val"
        },
        "itemId": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`$addFields` creates a field "0" in all array elements instead of using the ".0" as path selector to identify the target.

[The documentation states](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#behavior): `To add a field or fields to embedded documents (including documents in arrays) use the dot notation`

However I found it not to be the case here. What am I missing ?

I specifically need to add fields inside an existing object of unknown structure. I cannot re-write the whole element using $set for example.

Answer (score 1):

You may update the first element of the array via the aggregation pipeline.

Set the `field.array` value with:

1. Get the first element of the `field.array` array and add the `newField` field.
2. Get all the elements other than the first element of the `field.array` array.
3. Combine the result of (1) and (2) into an array.

```
db.users.updateOne{
  "_id": "F9F39JQH"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "field.array": {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              $mergeObjects: [
                {
                  $first: "$field.array"
                },
                {
                  "newField": "val"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          {
            $slice: [
              "$field.array",
              1,
              {
                $size: "$field.array"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KZ0pfUXKV4L)

Note that if you are using the MongoDB version 5.2 and above, you may consider replacing the `$slice` operator with [`$lastN`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/reference/operator/aggregation/lastN/).

```
{
  $lastN: {
    input: "$field.array",
    n: {
      $subtract: [
        {
          $size: "$field.array"
        },
        1
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note that you don't need to update with aggregation pipeline. You need the `$set` operator with dot notation.

```
db.users.updateOne({
  "_id": "F9F39JQH"
},
{
  $set: {
    "field.array.0.newField": "val"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`Here is the working live example:` https://mongoplayground.net/p/283qGaCzhFY

#### Data:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "F9F39JQH",
    "field": {
      "array": [
        {
          "itemId": 1
        },
        {
          "itemId": 2
        },
        {
          "itemId": 3
        },
        {
          "itemId": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

#### Aggregation:

```js
db.collection.updateOne({"_id": "F9F39JQH"},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "temp": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "$first": "$field.array"
          },
          {
            "newField": "provide_new_field_value"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "field.array": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          ["$temp"],
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$field.array",
              "cond": {
                "$ne": [
                  "$$this.itemId",
                  "$temp.itemId"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

#### Output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "F9F39JQH",
    "field": {
      "array": [
        {
          "itemId": 1,
          "newField": "provide_new_field_value"
        },
        {
          "itemId": 2
        },
        {
          "itemId": 3
        },
        {
          "itemId": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Live example URL` : https://mongoplayground.net/p/NoEpL5DkuCf

#### Below steps (step:1 & step:2) are only required if we have to get ID by Index

**step : 1**
We can firstly find the `itemId` via index using `$arrayElemtAt` and once we have element of specific index by using `aggregation` we can store the `ID` of element of that index in our `programming language variable` to use in furher **update aggregation.**

**step : 2**
we have stored the ID of object from `step:1` in `some variable of our programming langauge` now we can set in `arrayFilters`

```
    {
      "element.itemId": {
        $eq: "$ID"
      }
    }
```

to update the item it will `update the item of that index.`

**Below is the update aggregate : ID is known already (with direct ID of array element)**

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "F9F39JQH"
},
{
  $set: {
    "field.array.$[element].new_val": 100
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "element.itemId": {
        $eq: 1 //updating by id directly
      }
    }
  ],
  new: true
})
```